# Compilation error: CS0246 in an ASP.net MVC3 project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to follow this tutorial word for word. [MVC Music Store](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-9)
I'm already on part 9 however, when I try to press the button "Checkout" it shows this error message:

[image: Error]

1. Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Mvc3ToolsUpdateWeb_Default' could not be found.
2. public class _Page_Views_Account_LogOn_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage

I was thinking that, maybe I had added or deleted something, like a "usings" reference line, if that helps. So what I did was:

1. I tried to clean, build, rebuild the project and the solution.
2. Deleted temporary log files - restarted the computer.
3. I researched on the internet for similar errors such as this, but I didn't see anything. I also checked the comments on the tutorial however I didn't see any errors similar to mine.

The links I searched were: 
 
[My google search](https://www.google.com.ph/search?q=Compiler%20Error%20Message%3A%20CS0246%3A%20The%20type%20or%20namespace%20name%20%27Mvc3ToolsUpdateWeb_Default%27%20could%20not%20be%20found&oq=Compiler%20Error%20Message%3A%20CS0246%3A%20The%20type%20or%20namespace%20name%20%27Mvc3ToolsUpdateWeb_Default%27%20could%20not%20be%20found&aqs=chrome..69i57.767j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) 
[Stackoverflow search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=CS0246%3A%20The%20type%20or%20namespace%20name%20%20could%20not%20be%20found)

Kindly enlighten me on what to do. Thank youuuu!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from the screendump you provided, this has to do with authorization. in the addressbar you can see the Controller action you are trying to reach(redirect URL)

Check if your account controller is valid
[Link to account controller](https://github.com/robconery/mvcmusic/blob/master/MvcMusicStore/controllers/AccountController.cs)